# Embedding of Webbrowser in WPF Form with Address bar + Buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, event-handling, browser

I wouldlike to embed a webbrowser in a WPF application. The browser should look like a normal browser, with address bar, back and forward button and status bar. Is there a way how that could easily written in XAML, with a direct databinding of the address to a textbox, with a direct routing of events from the buttons to the webbrowser object, and the enabling back?

Comment: @user287107, you can use System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser, although i am not sure whether it would support binding of address box, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?
[Here](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/6062/79033795.jpg) and [here](http://img15.imageshack.us/i/36950879.jpg/) are uploaded some screenshots from our application which has WebModule inside and is able to work like browser.

In our implementation we used Windows Forms WebBrowser control as browser engine and MVVM as communication pattern. Model has navigation commands (forward, back, ...) that raise proper events. View is handling this events and delegate requested actions to inner WebBrowser component. Additionally view is handling WebBrowser's events (NewWindow, DocumentCompleted, Navigating, Navigated) and setting up model's state.

Model and view together contain about 500 lines of code (I don't think it's very much, do you?).

Of course, I should mention, that due to using IE engine this browser could have some problems on complicated web-sites.

P.S. We didn't use System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser because it does not provide access to NewWindow event.

P.P.S. I've posted this answer from browser in our WPF application. Good luck!